# Absolute path reference in swift framework created for distribution

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

I am creating a swift framework using Xcode 13.1. Swiftmodule which is part of the framework has reference to absolute path which will not work for frameworks that are supposed to be distributed. How do we change this to relative path from Xcode settings or config? Do we really need this swiftmodule in our distribution framework? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

All things that are distributed may it be app or framework needs to be included inside the bundle(project or framework). Then you can retrieve them like this

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
let resourcePath = bundle.path(forResource: "Seagull", ofType: "jpg")
```